# django sitemap xml file

Tags: django

hi I'm new in django I need to create a sitemap for my book modele but after doing this I can't find any xml file in my project directory .am i missed something?
 my sitemap.py is:

```
class BookSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "weekly"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Book.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.pub_date
```

url.py:

```
sitemaps = {
 'book':BookSitemap,
}
url(r'^sitemap.xml$',
'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.index',
{'sitemaps': sitemaps}),

url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+).xml$',
'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
{'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

setting.py

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

Comment: The xml file is generated on runtime, visit the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml` (if you are on local server) or `http://mydomain/sitemap.xml` (if you are on production server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/):

> This tells Django to build a sitemap when a client accesses /sitemap.xml.

the sitemap is not a static file, but it's an xml response each time somebody accesses your sitemap urls.
the fastest way to test if it's working is fire up your django server and point your browser to one of your sitemaps (http://localhost:8000/sitemap-< your section identifier>.xml, in your case) and you should see it